# Appending string in python without changing the variable name

Tags: python

Hi Team is there a way to append string in python, I mean i need to declare the variable globally and append the strings together and write in my file without changing the variable name.

For Example

```
example_string = ''
def method1():
    example_string = 'Value1'
def method2():
    example_string = 'value2'
def method3():
    example_string = 'value3'
print(example_string )
```

Now I want my the result to be printed as 'Value1 value2 value3', This is what im looking for can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` keyword to make changes to global variables in functions. Use `+=` to append to a string.

```
example_string = ''

def method1():
    global example_string
    example_string += 'value1'

def method2():
    global example_string
    example_string += 'value2'

def method3():
    global example_string
    example_string += 'value3'
```

Note that in order to get this last string you need to call all three functions

```
method1()
method2()
method3()
print(example_string)
```

Comment: Just note that 1/ global variables are evil and 2/ due to [what Python variables really are](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and namespacing rules rebinding (by opposition with mutating) a global will not necessarily behave as expected outside the module itself.

Comment: Shall i go with String concatenation

Comment: @Eager2Learn well, that depends on what you are actually doing. This is the most straightforward way to do what you asked for